# Details ViewController for MKAnnotation

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, viewcontroller

I'm trying to make a detail view after a user clicks on an MKAnnotation to switch over to a new view (in a NavigationController). I am looking into making the view similar to what you see what you click on an annotation in Apple Maps. I see a picture at the top of the view, followed by various entries of text.

I will need to show the following fields in my view and I want to display it in an organized way.

```
var business_name : String
var category : String
var address : String
var city : String
var type : String
var location : String
var valid : String
var comments : String
var date : String
var username : String
var additional_comment_count : String
```

How can I make my view look similar to what the Apple Maps detail view controller looks? Do I need to incorporate different types of views? Do I need to make my own custom views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a table view controller, with diferent type of cells. The top cell with have an image view, many of ther other cells are normal title/detail cell and the other cells look like they have collection views/scrollviews in them